# Remove first duplicate strings from text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove first duplicate month and year, I was able to remove the last duplicate words in text( ex. 30 December 2019 - 31 ). So my desired output example to be like this:  30 - 31 December 2019
This is what I have so far

```js
$('.dates p').each(function(){
var string = $(this).text();

var newdatarange = string.split(' ').filter(function(allItems,i,a){
    return i == a.indexOf(allItems);
}).join(' ');

$(this).text(newdatarange);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dates">
 <p>10 December 2019 - 12 December 2019</p>
 <p>14 December 2019 - 16 December 2019</p>
 <p>20 December 2019 - 22 December 2019</p>
 <p>30 December 2019 - 31 December 2019</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Using filter method also this can be solved, please check my answer below

Comment: using regular expression you can achieve it. `$(this).text($(this).text().trim().replace(/\w+\s\d{4}\s/,''));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could search for same parts and replace the string.

The regular expression looks for a capturing group which is repeated later.

```js
$('.dates p').each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/(\D+\s+\d+)(?=.*\1)/, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dates">
 <p>10 December 2019 - 12 December 2019</p>
 <p>14 December 2019 - 16 December 2019</p>
 <p>20 December 2019 - 22 December 2019</p>
 <p>30 December 2019 - 31 December 2019</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @RajshekarReddy, this does not check if the same substring occurs.

Comment: @NinaScholz thats correct, Your answer is great !! but from the example data he has provided I do not think his situation is as complex. BTW I placed my comment under your answer by mistake, I intended to put it under the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative if you don't love regex

```js
$('.dates p').each(function(){
   var string = $(this).text();

   var newdatarange = string.split('-');
   if(newdatarange.length==2){
if($.trim(newdatarange[0]).substring(3)==$.trim(newdatarange[1]).substring(3))
            string = $.trim(newdatarange[0]).substring(0, 2) + " - " + $.trim(newdatarange[1]).substring(0, 2) + " "+$.trim(newdatarange[0]).substring(3);
   }

   $(this).text(string);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dates">
 <p>10 December 2019 - 12 December 2019</p>
 <p>14 December 2019 - 16 December 2019</p>
 <p>20 December 2019 - 22 December 2019</p>
 <p>30 December 2019 - 31 December 2019</p>
</div>
```

Another option can be using filter method

```
$('.dates p').each(function(){
var string = $(this).text();

var newdatarange = string.split(' ').filter(function(allItems,i,a){
    return a.indexOf(allItems, i+1)==-1;
}).join(' ');

$(this).text(newdatarange);
});
```